# Как запускать скрипт только во время открытия меню?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

У меня следующая задача.
Есть блок "Мобильное меню" и есть кнопка "Клик".

При нажатии на кнопку, у мобильному меню переключается класс `menu-mobile_active`.
А при нажатии на область, помимо самого мобильного меню, у мобильного меню удаляется класс `menu-mobile_active` и всплывает alert с текстом, "мобильное меню скрыто".

Нужно сделать так, чтобы скрипт:
`$(document).mouseup(function(e) { ....});`
запускался только при открытом меню, т.е. только тогда, когда у мобильного меню есть класс `menu-mobile_active`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.menu-mobile').toggleClass('menu-mobile_active');
});

// Скрытие меню при клике на область помимо самого меню
$(document).mouseup(function(e) { // событие клика по веб-документ
  var div = $(".menu-mobile"); // тут указываем class элемента
  var toggle = $('.menu-toggle');
  if (!div.is(e.target) // если клик был не по нашему блоку
    &&
    !toggle.is(e.target) // и не по кнопке
    &&
    div.has(e.target).length === 0) { // и не по его дочерним элементам
    $(".menu-mobile").removeClass('menu-mobile_active');
    alert('Мобильное меню скрыто');
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-mobile {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  opacity: .3;
}

.menu-mobile_active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu-mobile">Мобильное меню</div>
<button class="menu-toggle">Клик</button>
```

Comment: Кто мешает вместо `.toggleClass()` использовать `.addClass(className)` и `.removeClass(className)`? По условию проверяйте наличие нужного класса и выполняйте что необходимо.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте проверку на класс

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.menu-mobile').toggleClass('menu-mobile_active');
});

// Скрытие меню при клике на область помимо самого меню
$(document).mouseup(function(e) { // событие клика по веб-документ
  const div = $(".menu-mobile"); // тут указываем class элемента
  const toggle = $('.menu-toggle');
  if(!toggle.hasClass('menu-mobile_active')) return // проверить, есть ли класс
  if (!div.is(e.target) // если клик был не по нашему блоку
    &&
    !toggle.is(e.target) // и не по кнопке
    &&
    div.has(e.target).length === 0) { // и не по его дочерним элементам
    $(".menu-mobile").removeClass('menu-mobile_active');
    alert('Мобильное меню скрыто');
  }
});
```